# Bootstrap multiple carousel with pagination dots

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Bootstrap framework and I'm having trouble trying to set multiple carousel with pagination dots on the same page. I used the bootstrap-carousel.js updated script on GitHub (the one with pills option) to do the pagination.

I found a solution for multiple carousel with next-prev navigation but nothing about multiple  carousel with dot.

Any ideas to fix this problem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please share a link or a demo?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/fSGnG/)

Require the `bootstrap-carousel.js` and the carousel.less.

```
(function(){ $('head style[type="text/css"]').attr('type', 'text/less');less.refreshStyles(); })();

$('#myCarousel').carousel();
```

Answer (score 1):

With latest carousel, you can use **carousel-indicators** class:

```
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel